# NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate dateStyle results

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm creating this question so I can have a one-shot reference to all the date and time styles for each of the `NSDateFormatterStyle` enum values `NSDateFormatterShortStyle, NSDateFormatterMediumStyle, NSDateFormatterLongStyle, NSDateFormatterFullStyle`.

I often find myself in a position where I'd like to know if these default styles are sufficient for my clients, and it's hard to find all the styles in one place.

Comment: Use [`dateFormatFromTemplate(_:options:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:) and you will get a localized date with all and only the components you need.

Comment: I am aware of the more specific possibilities of NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

All the output below is in order `1 = NSDateFormatterShortStyle, 2 = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle, 3 = NSDateFormatterLongStyle, 4 = NSDateFormatterFullStyle`.  Please feel free to comment if you'd prefer a different organization of output.

**English**

```
2015-03-27, 9:42 AM 
Mar 27, 2015, 9:42:45 AM
March 27, 2015 at 9:42:45 AM EDT
Friday, March 27, 2015 at 9:42:45 AM Eastern Daylight Time
```

Note that the Date Formatter separates Date & Time by "," in Short and Medium styles, and by "at" in long and full styles.  Interesting!

**French**

```
2015-03-27 09:54
2015-03-27 09:54:07
27 mars 2015 09:54:07 HAE
vendredi 27 mars 2015 09 h 54 min 07 s heure avancée de l’Est
```

No commas at all here.  French dates seem to be 24h.

**German**

```
27.03.15 09:58
27.03.2015 09:58:07
27. März 2015 09:58:07 GMT-4
Freitag, 27. März 2015 09:58:07 Nordamerikanische Ostküsten-Sommerzeit
```

**Spanish**

```
27/3/15 10:00
27/3/2015 10:00:05
27 de marzo de 2015, 10:00:05 GMT-4
viernes, 27 de marzo de 2015, 10:00:05 (Hora de verano oriental)
```

**Simplified Chinese**

```
15/3/27 上午10:01
2015年3月27日 上午10:01:40
2015年3月27日 GMT-4上午10:01:40
2015年3月27日 星期五 北美东部夏令时间上午10:01:40
```